# python - convert dynamic string to variable

Tags: python, string, variables

I know there are quite a few threads about this matter, but I couldn't get it working so far. At the moment it prints the string and not the actual value (i.E. 12, 20,..)

```
import time

global a1
global v1
a1 = 0.4
v1 = 0.5

global varZup
global varZdown
varZup=0.0065
varZdown=0

xx00=12
yy00=12
zz00=12
rx00=12
ry00=12
rz00=12

xx01=20
yy01=20
rx01=20
ry01=20
rz01=20

xx02=312
yy02=312
rx02=312
ry02=312
rz02=312

xx03=41
yy03=41
rx03=41
ry03=41
rz03=41

global varCnt
varCnt = 0

global posCnt
posCnt = 0

while posCnt < 40:
        sendx = "xx" + str(varCnt).zfill(2)
        sendy = "yy" + str(varCnt).zfill(2)
        sendrx = "rx" + str(varCnt).zfill(2)
        sendry = "ry" + str(varCnt).zfill(2)
        sendrz = "rz" + str(varCnt).zfill(2)
        #print(eval('sendx'))
        #exec("%s = %d" % (sendx,int(sendx)))
        #print("movep(p[" + exec(str(sendx)) + ", " + exec(str(sendy)) + ", " + "{:.5f}".format(varZup) + ", " + exec(str(sendrx)) + ", " + exec(str(sendry)) + ", " + exec(str(sendrz)) + "], a=" + "{:.5f}".format(a1) + ", v=" + "{:.5f}".format(v1) + ", r=0)")
        print("movep(p[" + sendx + ", " + sendy + ", " + "{:.5f}".format(varZup) + ", " + sendrx + ", " + sendry + ", " + sendrz + "], a=" + "{:.5f}".format(a1) + ", v=" + "{:.5f}".format(v1) + ", r=0)")
        #s.send(("movep(p[" + "{:.5f}".format(sendx) + ", " + "{:.5f}".format(sendy) + ", " + "{:.5f}".format(varzUp) + ", " + "{:.5f}".format(sendrx) + ", " + "{:.5f}".format(sendry) + ", " + "{:.5f}".format(sendrz) + "], a=" + "{:.5f}".format(a1) + ", v=" + "{:.5f}".format(v1) + ", r=0)" + "\n").encode("utf8"))
        varCnt+=1
        time.sleep(1)
```

My tries with exec and eval failed so far (there ist nothing to execute), also it would be nice to get a one liner for the conversion and "send" command.

I just wan't to "fill in" the variables into the string that gets sent to a robot later.

EDIT:
this works and gets better with every edit

```
my_list0 = [0.11946,-0.27553,-0.00058,3.14098,0.00296]
my_list1 = [0.24737,-0.27553,2.20186,-2.23966,-0.00281]
my_list2 = [0.31433,-0.27552,2.20190,-2.23959,-0.00277]
my_list3 = [0.38954,-0.27554,2.20182,-2.23973,-0.00289]
call_list = [my_list0, my_list1, my_list2, my_list3]

while True:
   print(*call_list[varCnt][0:1], sep=", ")
   print(*call_list[varCnt][3:4], sep=", ")
   print("")
   varCnt+=1
   time.sleep(1)
```

EDIT2:
now I need to compare some data using "math", how to get floats in or out of these lists?

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

```
        compareX = map(float, *call_list[varCnt][0:1])
        compareY = map(float, *call_list[varCnt][1:2])
        compare = math.isclose(compareX-xAct, compareY-yAct, abs_tol=0.0001)
```

Comment: Don't use variables of the form `xx00`, `xx01`, etc. Use a list called `xx` and address the values as  `xx[varCnt]`.

Comment: `my_list = [['12', ...], ['17', ...], ...]` `print(my_list[0])`!

Comment: can you please check out my edited first post?

Comment: That's already what my above comment pertains to.

Comment: I know how to read out single values from the list, my question is how to use a counter to address the listnames. My approach to fix the original issue could be completely wrong. From my code in the edited first post I would expect fully printed lists -> my_list0-3

Comment: And the answer is to create a list of lists, not sequentially numbered variables.

Comment: "EDIT: this doesn't work unfortunately" -- define "doesn't work"

Comment: Note that you can save yourself a bit of typing by declaring a list of lists immediately as I showed above, instead of creating individual variables which you then stuff into a list.

Comment: 1st post edited again - getting close, but how to get rid of the [ ] in the terminal output?

Comment: `print(*call_list[varCnt][0:1])`…?

Comment: thanks, this works great for the moment. I might run into other problems later

Comment: now I need to math compare some of the data, please take a look at edit2

Comment: got it working, converting to string first and later to float